# How to convert text to date in Google Sheets? Jul '19 will become 07/2019

Tags: regex, date, google-sheets, string-formatting, google-sheets-formula

How to convert a text to date in Google Sheets?

```
Jul '19
```

will become

```
07/2019
```

I have tried using the format option. It didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
=TEXT(DATE(20&RIGHT(A1, 2), MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.+)'")&1), 1), "mm/yyyy")
```

[image: 0]

---

or like:

```
=TEXT(MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "(.+)'")&1), "00")&"/20"&RIGHT(A1, 2)
```

[image]